# Shortcut to pantheon-terminal opens tab instead of new window

Tags: pantheon-terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to create a keyboard shortcut for opening a program in a new terminal. So I went to System Settings - Keyboard - Shortcuts - Custom and assigned the command `pantheon-terminal -e htop` to a key combination.

If no terminal is open, this works perfectly. It opens a new terminal with the program. But when one or more terminals are open, it just creates a new tab in one of the open ones. And don't even focus the terminal.

Is there a way to open the program in a complete new window?

Answer (score 1):

Still haven't found the solution for pantheon-terminal, however if you don't mind installing gnome-terminal you have this

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "./myscript.sh"
```

UPDATE:
Running `pantheon-terminal -e htop` never worked for me, however 
you can change the terminal to open without tabs at all.
Install gsettings

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

then go to "org > pantheon > terminal > settings"
double click on "tab-bar-behavior" and select "never show tabs"

Hope it helps

Comment: Switching to the `gnome-terminal` might be an option, though I would lie. Your second solution doesn't work though. It only hides the tab-bar, but the tabs are still there.

Comment: "though I would lie"??? I probably should have read before hitting the submit button. I wanted to write, that I would like a solution, that doesn't include another terminal emulator.

Comment: lol, I was wondering about the lie thing.. anyway I didn't find how I can run it with a command inside. there's no mentioning of this option in the help. I didn't find anything in the code either, but I didn't dig to deep

Answer (score 0):

There is no command line argument to open a new window in a running `pantheon-terminal` instance.

There is a keyboard shortcut to open a new terminal window, but not with any commands to run in it: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>.